# Como usar foreign key nas instruções SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou querendo usar o foreign key mas não estou conseguindo. Esta instrução **SQL** vai criar uma tabela chamada `tbl_estado` com 4 colunas `id, nome, uf, pais` e na coluna `pais` vai entrar o foreign key que vai ser buscado na `tbl_pais` o `id` do país que é a coluna `id`.

$aonde = `axitech20` (banco)

$tablep = `tbl_pais`

$tablee = `tbl_estado`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$sql8   = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $aonde.$tablee (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            nome        VARCHAR(75) DEFAULT NULL,
            uf          VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL,
            pais        INT(6) DEFAULT NULL KEY '??????????' ($tablep)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=28";
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer o relacionamento que é alguma coisa ali no **??????????** da instrução. Podem me ajudar a acertar o `foreign key`?

Comment: Já tentou verificar na [documentação do mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) ?

Comment: Tentei sim foi assim que consegui criar a instrução mas não estou acertando as instruções que vão ali `???????`

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (product_category, product_id) REFERENCES product(category, id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dessa forma deve funcionar:

```
CREATE TABLE axitech20.tb1_pais (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE axitech20.tbl_estado (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_pais INT NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(75),
    uf VARCHAR(5),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_pais) REFERENCES tb1_pais(id)
);
```

Comment: A minha dúvida é justamente por causa do prefixo do nome das tabelas. Pode aplicar este código levando em consideração o prefixo `tbl_` por favor. Já marco sua resposta como correta.

Comment: Assim deve funcionar, qualquer erro me avise!

Comment: Esse `(id_pais)` tá certo?

Comment: id_pais é referente a coluna da tabela tbl_estado que vai receber o valor do id de uma das tuplas (linhas) da tabela  tbl_pais. Você pode colocar outro nome se quiser